# clang error: c++/4.8/bits/stl_iterator_base_types.h:227:29: error: no type named 'iterator_category' in 'std::iterator_traits<unsigned long>'

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, libc++

Custom built clang 3.1 was unable to find some machine-dependent include files(like `bits/c++config.h`) from libc++, so I had to add manually: `-I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/4.8` into command line. gcc has no problem finding those files.

Now I am trying to compile a file with clang++. gcc(with the same options) compiles it, complaining only with a bunch of warnings, when clang++ unable to do that, referring to an error in the standard library:

```
In file included from /home/necto/proj/klein/lib/Core/PPLSupport.cpp:2:
In file included from /home/necto/proj/klein/build/llvm/include/llvm/Constant.h:17:
In file included from /home/necto/proj/klein/build/llvm/include/llvm/User.h:22:
In file included from /home/necto/proj/klein/build/llvm/include/llvm/Support/ErrorHandling.h:19:
In file included from /home/necto/proj/klein/build/llvm/include/llvm/ADT/StringRef.h:18:
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../include/c++/4.8/string:39:
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../include/c++/4.8/bits/char_traits.h:38:
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algobase.h:65:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_iterator_base_types.h:227:29: error: no type named 'iterator_category' in 'std::iterator_traits<unsigned long>'
            iterator_traits<_InIter>::iterator_category,
            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_vector.h:391:25: note: in instantiation of template type alias '_RequireInputIter' requested here
           typename = std::_RequireInputIter<_InputIterator>>
                           ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_vector.h:392:9: note: in instantiation of default argument for 'vector<unsigned long>' required here
    vector(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last,
    ^~~~~~
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_vector.h:392:9: note: while substituting deduced template arguments into function template 'vector' [with _InputIterator = unsigned long, $1 = ]
    vector(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last,
```

clang version 3.1 
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix

gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2

How should I proceed in further investigation? What information would be useful here?

Comment: Have you tried to compile with -lstdc++ option?

Comment: Just tried - nothing changed

Comment: Just a note: "bits/c++config.h" is not a libc++ file; it is a libstdc++ file.
The file starts out:

    // This file is part of the GNU ISO C++ Library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade your `clang` version, it's very likely that `clang 3.1` can't deal with the `4.8 libstdc++` headers.

http://llvm.org/releases/download.html
http://llvm.org/apt